# How to change Google Maps JavaScript API Polygon marker styling

Tags: javascript, google-maps, styling

I'd like to change the styling of the polygon markers (generated by DrawingManager) in Google Maps JavaScript API.

This is what I have now
[image]

What I'd like to do is make the white circles with blue outlines larger than they are right now. I see where I can modify colors, but not size, shape, or position. Where should I look for this? Has anyone accomplished what I'm trying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by using a mutation observer to listen for DOM additions:

```
 /**  
 * Check if Node is a dot and update styles
 * @param {Node} node - Node to examine and possibly update
 */
const checkIfNodeIsADotAndUpdateStyles = node => {
  const STYLE_ADDITIONS =
    '; height: 25px; width: 25px; border-radius: 100%; left: -2px; top: -2px;'

  const styleAttr = node.getAttribute('style')
  const correctHeight = styleAttr.includes('height: 9px')
  const correctWidth = styleAttr.includes('width: 9px')
  const correctRadius = styleAttr.includes('border-radius: 6px')

  if (correctWidth && correctHeight && correctRadius) {
    node.setAttribute('style', styleAttr + STYLE_ADDITIONS)
  }
}

/**
 * Check passed in `mutationList` for added nodes. If any nodes were added,
 * pass them to `checkIfNodeIsADotAndUpdateStyles`.
 * @param  {MutationRecord[]} mutationsList - Mutation list to iterate over
 */
const checkForAndProcessAddedNodes = (mutationsList) => {
  try {
    mutationsList.forEach(mutation => {
      if (mutation.type === 'childList' && mutation.addedNodes.length > 0) {
        mutation.addedNodes.forEach(checkIfNodeIsADotAndUpdateStyles)
      }
    })
  } catch (err) {
    logger.warn(err)
  }
}

/**
 * Listen for changes to the DOM
 * @see {@link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver}
 * @param  {HTMLElement} ref - DOM element to observe
 * @return {Function} - MutationObserver disconnect function
 */
export const listenForDomChanges = (ref) => {
  // Setup observer to listen for additions/removals
  const config = { childList: true, subtree: true }

  // Create an observer that calls `checkForAndProcessAddedNodes` on mutations
  const observer = new MutationObserver(checkForAndProcessAddedNodes)

  // Start observing the target
  observer.observe(ref, config)

  // Return disconnect function
  return observer.disconnect
}
```